# How to get the attribute value of a <TR> tag of which <TD> tag has "KK" attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, attributes

I need to get the "pp" attribute value of TR tag 
which has a TD tag having "KK" attribute.

```
<TR pp="I hava to read this.">
    <TD kk >  </TD>
</TR>
<TR pp="Don't want this...">
    <TD > </TD>
</TR>
```

How can i do this with 1 line jQuery command?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var elem = $("tr td").filter(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).attr("kk") !== undefined
}).parent("tr").attr("pp");
```

```js
var elem = $("tr td").filter(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).attr("kk") !== undefined
}).parent("tr").attr("pp");

console.log(elem)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<TR pp="I hava to read this.">
    <TD kk>  </TD>
</TR>
<TR pp="Don't want this...">
    <TD> </TD>
</TR>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TR pp="I hava to read this.">
<TD data-test="kk" >  </TD>
</TR>
<TR pp="Don't want this...">
    <TD > </TD>
</TR>
```

## var td_you_want = $('td').data('test');

Answer (score 0):

```
var pp_text = $("td[kk]").parent().attr("pp");
```